# Comments in expression builder get removed when deploying ADF pipelines via ARM template

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-data-factory

I have some steps in my ADF pipeline that could use some comments. As an example, I have an aggregate step that creates a new column with comma separated values:

```
/* initialize #acc as empty string, add #item if #acc is empty, otherwise add: , #item */
reduce(collect(value), '', #acc + iif(#acc == '', '', ', ') + #item, #result)
```

In the ARM this looks like (ARM template was generated from ADFs export template function):

```
   ...
   "script": "[concat('
      source(
      ...
      commaseparated_values = /* initialize #acc as empty string, add #item if #acc is empty, otherwise add: , #item */\r\nreduce(collect(value), '', #acc + iif(#acc == '', '', ', ') + #item, #result), 
      ...
      ')]"
```

When I deploy ADF using this template however, the comment is gone from the expression:
[image: Screenshot from ADF expression builder window]

I tried escaping the `/` with a `\` in the ARM, but the comment still does not show up in ADF expression builder. How can I get the comments in expressions deployed via ARM?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried escaping the / in the ARM, but the comment still does not show
> up in ADF expression builder. How can I get the comments in
> expressions deployed via ARM?

- One of the workaround could be resolve the above issue
  Instead of using `/*.../*`  we can use this `/* ....... */` for commenting expresion .

For more information please refer this **Microsoft Documentation**: [***Build expressions in mapping data flow***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-expression-builder#commenting-expressions)

Comment: Sorry, that was an error in copy pasting to SO. The comments are actually correctly formatted. The issue is that I can add comments in the expression builder in ADF, but after exporting the template, and deploying it via DevOps, the comments disappear from ADF, (and also the template when exporting it again)

Answer (score 0):

Use ***version 2.3.0*** or later if you're deploying the ARM Templates using Azure CLI and specify the **`--handle-extended-json-format`** switch.

In VS Code, if you see the ARM Template word at bottom which means it detected the language mode, use the Inline comments which are valid.
[image]

Also try setting up the comments in multi-line syntax once to see multi-line comments are reflecting or not.

For more information related to multi-line comment sytanx, refer this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/syntax#multi-line-strings).

In Research, many issues related to comments in ARM Templates were due to improper format of Json, previous Azure CLI versions are not supported comments because JSON.Net handles comments so solved using `--handle-extended-json-format` as I have mentioned in the starting point.

**References:**

1. https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/issues/851
2. https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/issues/2112

Comment: I don't want to add a comment in the ARM template. The comment is part of an expression builder textbox in an ADF dataflow. Somehow the comment is not being written when deploying ADF. I think the ARM parser might incorrectly remove is. I am using AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment (v3.196.0) task in the yaml pipeline to deploy this template.